# How to construct a tree from a preorder traversal

Tags: list-manipulation, trees

The list

```
t1 = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2};
```

might be derived from a pre-order traversal of

```
tree1 = Tree[1, {Tree[2, {3, Tree[3, {4, 4}], 3, Tree[3, {4}], 3, 3}], 
  Tree[2, {Tree[3, {4}]}], Tree[2, {3}], 2}]
```

But how to take the original list, `t1` here, and build the tree `tree1` ?

What have I tried so far ?  Nothing to any avail!  Well, that's not quite true, I have made some progress with a very procedural code to walk along the list and try to figure out the structure of the tree as each new element is read, but I have a dispiriting feeling that I have missed an obvious usage of some of the smarter functional programming functionality.

Comment: So the second argument (in your use-cases) would always be a nonempty list? For instance, `Tree[4, {}]` could not occur?

Comment: No, `Tree[n,{}]` shouldn't occur, that would just be a leaf at level `n`.  `Tree` looks quite neat and I'm trying to figure out how to use it to replace a lot of old code I have which uses the existing Graph type for manipulating what are really Trees.

Comment: Yep, `TreeForm` has been around so long, it's about time something like `Tree` has surfaced at the user level.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another way:

```
toTree // ClearAll;
toTree[{n_}] := Tree[n, None];
toTree[t_List] :=
  Tree[First[t], toTree /@ Split[Rest@t, #2 != t[[2]] &]];

t1 = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2};
toTree[t1]
```

[image]

As @IanFord points out, `NestTree[]` can do the nesting of trees that `toTree[]` does explicitly:

```
children[t_List] := Split[Rest[t], #2 != t[[2]] &];
NestTree[children, t1, Infinity, First]
```

Comment: Sweet.  Short and to the point.

Comment: ... and the points go to ... this answer !  This one strikes me as the most Mathematica-y one, there's rather a whiff of procedurality about the others.

Comment: This method can be used with NestTree: `children[t_List] := Split[Rest[t], #2 != t[[2]] &];
NestTree[children, t1, Infinity, First]`

Comment: @IanFord Thanks! and welcome to Mma.SE! I have not yet had time to explore all the new tree functions.

Answer (score 5):

You may use [`SequenceReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceReplace.html).

```
traversalToTree[traversal_] :=
 First@Nest[
    Map[
      SequenceReplace[{n_, b : Longest[Except[n_] ..]} :> \[FormalT][n, {b}]]
      , #
      , {-2}
      ] &
    , traversal
    , Length@*DeleteDuplicates@traversal
    ] /. \[FormalT] -> Tree
```

`traversalToTree` repeatedly applies `SequenceReplace` to the second last level of the building tree. Unfortunately using `Tree` in the replace does not target the correct level so formal t is used and later replaced.

With

```
t1 = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2};
```

then

```
traversalToTree[t1]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The nodes in the traversal can be any [`AtomQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AtomQ.html) expression.

```
traversalToTree[t1 /. {1 -> "z", 2 -> 2.5, 3 -> π, 4 -> "a"}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hopes this helps.

Comment: Very useful, many thanks.  `SequenceReplace` is new to me.  I'll see if I can wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the tree rules, inspired me to construct that as a string, then by `ToExpression` bring it to life.

#### TreeRules

```
tr = Tree[1, {Tree[2, {3, Tree[3, {4, 4}], 3, Tree[3, {4}], 3, 3}], 
    Tree[2, {Tree[3, {4}]}], Tree[2, {3}], 2}];

TreeRules[tr]

(*Out: 1 -> {2 -> {3, 3 -> {4, 4}, 3, 3 -> {4}, 3, 3}, 2 -> {3 -> {4}}, 2 -> {3}, 2} *)
```

#### Code

```
ClearAll[listToTree];

listToTree::invalid = "Input list is invalid."

listToTree[data_List] := 
 With[{temp = 
    ToString@First@data <> 
     StringJoin@
      MapIndexed[
       Function[{x, y}, 
        With[{next = data[[First@y + 1]]}, 
         Which[next == x + 1, "\[Rule]{", next < x, 
           StringRepeat["}", x - next] <> ",", x == next, ","] <> 
          ToString@next]], Most@data]}, 

  With[{finalTemp = temp <> StringRepeat["}", 
       StringCount[temp, "{"] - StringCount[temp, "}"]]}, 
   If[SyntaxQ@finalTemp, RulesTree@ToExpression[finalTemp], 
    Message[listToTree::invalid]]]]
```

#### Example

```
listToTree[{1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2}]
```

[image]

```
listToTree[{1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that looks very useful.  I'd had that thought too, of transforming the list to a string for manipulation, then back to a `Tree`, but my nascent solution is neither complete nor as neat as yours.  I await a solution which does not require stringification !

Answer (score 2):

```
toEdges = Module[{f}, Rest @* MapIndexed[(f[# + 1] = #2[[1]]; f @ # -> #2[[1]])&]]

t1 // toEdges // Graph // GraphTree // TreeMap[t1[[#]]&]
```

[image]

Comment: Gosh, that's neat.  And much appreciated.  I'll poke this around a bit, maybe do some comparisons with the answer I already accepted.

Answer (score 2):

```
treeExp = First[#] @@ (#0 /@ Split[Rest@#, {a, b} |-> b != #[[2]]]) /. a_[] :> a &;

treeExp @ t1
```

> ```
> 1[2[3, 3[4, 4], 3, 3[4], 3, 3], 2[3[4]], 2[3], 2]
> ```

```
ExpressionTree @ treeExp @ t1
```

[image]

```
InputForm @ %
```

> ```
> Tree[1, {Tree[2, {Tree[3, None], Tree[3, {Tree[4, None], Tree[4, None]}], 
>  Tree[3, None], Tree[3, {Tree[4, None]}], Tree[3, None], Tree[3, None]}], 
>  Tree[2, {Tree[3, {Tree[4, None]}]}], Tree[2, {Tree[3, None]}], Tree[2, None]}]
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this answer too.